Showing blank page instead of saving when records are more
I have created a Stocktake page which is saving perfectly fine when records are less but when we have more items, when we save, the page doesn't saves and shows a blank page. I couldn't figure out how to fix this. The following is the code from my Stocktake Controller:
if(isset($_POST['save'])){

                $location = $this->input->post('location');
                $loc = explode("-",$location,2);
                $location_id = $loc[0];
                $location_name =$loc[1];

                $stk_number = $this->input->post('stk_number');
                $item_id = $this->input->post('item_id');
                $item_name = $this->input->post('item_name');
                $measure_unit = $this->input->post('measure_unit');
                $barcode = $this->input->post('barcode');
                $category_id = $this->input->post('category_id');
                $stocktake_quantity = $this->input->post('stocktake_quantity');
                $comment = $this->input->post('comment');
                $date = $this->input->post('date');
                $expiry_date = $this->input->post('expiry_date');

                

                // Save Stock Take
                $data = array(
                    'stk_number' => $this->input->post('stk_number'),
                    'location' => $location_name,
                    'location_id' => $location_id,
                    'comment' => $this->input->post('comment'),
                    'status' => '1',
                    'created_at' => $this->input->post('date'),
                    'created_by' => $this->session->userdata('name')
                );
    
                $this->db->insert('stocktake', $data);
                $stk_id = $this->db->insert_id();
                
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($stocktake_quantity); $i++) 
                {
                    if($stocktake_quantity[$i] != ''){           
                        
                        $no_expiry = '0';
                        if($expiry_date[$i] == '0000-00-00'){
                            $no_expiry = '1';
                        }
                        $data = [
                            'stk_number' => $stk_number,
                            'stk_id' => $stk_id,
                            'item_id' => $item_id[$i],
                            'item_name' => $item_name[$i],
                            'measure_unit' => $measure_unit[$i],
                            'barcode' => $barcode[$i],
                            'category_id' => $category_id[$i],
                            'stocktake_quantity' => $stocktake_quantity[$i],
                            'no_expiry' => $no_expiry,
                            'status' => '1',
                            'detail' => 'stock take',
                            'date' => $date
                        ];

                        $this->db->insert('stocktake_trans', $data);
                    }
                }

                // Set message
                $this->session->set_flashdata('stocktake_saved', 'Stock Take has been saved!');

                redirect('stocktake');

            }

I print_r($_POST) to check if everything is being passed but I noticed $_POST['save'] is not passing when the records exceed certain limit but if the records are less then it is passed. Any other hidden or input field data also doesn't passes when the records exceed. Some categories have less item records and some have more, I'm facing this problem while choosing categories with more items. It's showing only 124 records for each array which is way less, right now I have more than 400 records in some categories which will increase in the future.

It sounds like you're going over some post limit. It could be post_max_size, max_input_vars or anything related to posting. See: Description of core php.ini directives. I cannot really judge from your code what you're actually posting. You can also use your browser developer tools to see what is posted.

A blank page could be a 500/Internal Server Error. Have you checked your server error logs?

@aynber That was my first though also, but if you read the question it says that print_r($_POST) works, and it wouldn't on an error 500. So, it's not really a blank page after all.

@KIKOSoftware  I increased the post_max_size and especially max_input_vars and it worked wonderfully!! Thank you so much!! :)
How can I mark your answer, you've been so kind :)

what  is your form code ? please post that too
